# when i try to access redux state it returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I can dispatch my state but i have problem with with accesing it in redux

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import AuthenticationPage from './AuthenticationPage';
import '../styles/App.css';
import SignOut from './SignOut';
import{TOGGLE_LOGIN} from "../redux/actionTypes"
import{connect} from 'react-redux'

function App(props) {

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('IsUserLogged')==="true"){
      props.toggleLogin();
    }
    console.log(props.isLogged);    //console show undefined  
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {props.isLogged===true?
      <SignOut/>:
      <AuthenticationPage/>}
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  return{
    isLogged: state.isLogged
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch=>{
  return{
    toggleLogin: ()=>dispatch({type: TOGGLE_LOGIN})
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

I have redux dev tools installed and It shows me that my state is working 
[image]

i can also toggle my state with props.toggleLogin(),[image]

but when i try to get value of my state with props.isLogged it returns undefined instead of true/false.

here is my redux code:

***reducers/logIn.js***

```
import{TOGGLE_LOGIN} from "../actionTypes"

const initialState={
    isLogged: false,
}

const LogInReducer = (state=initialState, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case TOGGLE_LOGIN:{
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isLogged: !state.isLogged
            })
        }
        default:{
            return state;
        }
    }
}

export default LogInReducer;
```

***reducers/index.js***

```
import{combineReducers} from "redux";
import LogInReducer from './logIn.js';

export default combineReducers({
    LogInReducer
})
```

***actions.js***

```
import{TOGGLE_LOGIN} from "./actionTypes"

export const ToggleLogin=()=>({
        type: TOGGLE_LOGIN
});
```

***actionTypes.js***

```
export const TOGGLE_LOGIN="TOGGLE_LOGIN";
});
```

***store.js***

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

export default createStore(rootReducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());
```

Comment: What happens once you create a separate `useEffect` hook just to log the value of `isLogged` state? Like `useEffect(() => { console.log(props.isLogged); }, [props.isLogged])`. **+1**: Also one comment, I guess probably `useDispatch` and `useSelector` are better fit for function component instead of `mapDispatchToProps` and `mapStateToProps`. Check out one of my repositories if you are interested in a working example for those: https://github.com/norbitrial/react-redux-loading-data-example

Comment: @norbitrial, by using `useDispatch`, you're making the FC aware of Redux, which probably isn't what you want in all cases. Note `connect()` is an HOC.

Comment: Joseph answer helped me and it works now, thanks for your recommendation, i will check it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in your `combineReducer` you have a `LogInReducer` key.

So the state is actually `LogInReducer.isLogged` (which is also seen in your redux-dev-tool screenshot).

You may want to do this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { isLogged } = state.LogInReducer;

  return {
    isLogged
  };
}
```